# Restart Python script if finish or crash Windows

Tags: python-2.7

Now I have a infinite loop in my code for the script restart when finish.  The problem is when script crash.
How I can restart script if crash?

infiniteloop.py

```
while True:
execfile("abc.py")
```

abc.py

```
print "1"

error
```

Comment: no real answer for this yet...?

Answer (score 2):

Do like this,

```
while True:
   try:
      execfile("abc.py")
   except Exception as e:
      print "Exception occured: ", e
```

Comment: Code do what I need thanks, but if possible print what error make script stop before restart?

Comment: updated the answer. check. Also, check this [link](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#user-defined-exceptions)
This might help to define your own kind of exception for your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably not any way to have the script restart itself once it's crashed, but you could add some error handling like so:

```
while True:
    try:
        execfile("abc.py")
    except:
        pass
```

Alternatively, you could use shell scripting to run your wrapper repeatedly.